# javascript - using a variable in getElementById

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I use a variable in getElementById

html:

```
   <td><a href="#" onclick='selectEditActivity("id3319201010153333");'>Click</a></td>
```

javascript:

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){  
  // this works
  alert(pass_id)
  // this works;
  var A = document.getElementById("id33192010101533333").getAttribute("seq");
  alert(A);
  // but this does not when I use the variable

  var B = document.getElementById(pass_id).getAttribute("seq");
  alert(B);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `3` in your `onclick` handler. It should be:

```
onclick='selectEditActivity("id33192010101533333");'
```

Instead of:

```
onclick='selectEditActivity("id3319201010153333");'
```

Answer (score 1):

`id33192010101533333` is not the same thing as `id3319201010153333`. One of them has an extra `3` at the end.

Use the same ID in your variable and it'll work fine.